# Displaying 25 inputs into a 5x5 grid using -ffmpeg- with the correct layout code

Tags: video, ffmpeg, command-line, video-processing

I'm now looking to expand [the 4x4 code very helpfully provided by @llogan yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68980788/mixing-and-overlaying-audio-into-a-4x4-video-with-ffmpeg) into one taking 25 different and equally-scaled audio and video inputs to make a 5x5 grid (at which point, I'll stop):

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4 -i c.mp4 -i d.mp4 -i e.mp4 -i f.mp4 -i g.mp4 -i h.mp4 -i i.mp4 -i j.mp4 -i k.mp4 -i l.mp4 -i m.mp4 -i n.mp4 -i o.mp4 -i p.mp4 -i q.mp4 -i r.mp4 -i s.mp4 -i t.mp4 -i u.mp4 -i v.mp4 -i w.mp4 -i x.mp4 -i y.mp4 \
 -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v0];[1:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v1];[2:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v2]; \ 
     [3:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v3];[4:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v4];[5:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v5]; \ 
     [6:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v6];[7:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v7];[8:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v8]; \ 
     [9:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v9];[10:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v10];[11:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v11]; \
     [12:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v12];[13:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v13];[14:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v14]; \
     [15:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v15];[16:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v16];[17:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v17]; \ 
     [18:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v18];[19:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v19];[20:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v20]; \
     [21:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v21];[22:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v22];[23:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v23]; \ 
     [24:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v24]; \
     [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4][v5][v6][v7][v8][v9][v10][v11][v12][v13][v14][v15][v16][v17][v18][v19][v20][v21][v22][v23][v24]xstack=inputs=25:layout=0_0|0_h0|0_h0+h1|0_h0+h1+h2|0_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0_0|w0_h0|w0_h0+h1|w0_h0+h1+h2|w0_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0+w4_0|w0+w4_h0|w0+w4_h0+h1|w0+w4_h0+h1+h2|w0+w4_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0+w4+w8_0|w0+w4+w8_h0|w0+w4+w8_h0+h1|w0+w4+w8_h0+h1+h2|w0+w4+w8_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0+w4+w8+w12_0|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0+h1|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0+h1+h2|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0+h1+h2+h3; \
     [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a][6:a][7:a][8:a][9:a][10:a][11:a][12:a][13:a][14:a][15:a][16:a][17:a][18:a][19:a][20:a][21:a][22:a][23:a][24:a]amix=inputs=25" \
output.mp4
```

Unfortunately, this produces errors:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Ubuntu 10.2.1-20ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libaribb24 --enable-liblensfun --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'abc.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 248 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 41 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 193 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'ang.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 480 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 271 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'ard.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 49 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #2:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 193 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'atv.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:17.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 259 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 53 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #3:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 193 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bor.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 255 kb/s
    Stream #4:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 48 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #4:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cen.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 461 kb/s
    Stream #5:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 250 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #5:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cha.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 267 kb/s
    Stream #6:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 59 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #6:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #7, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'grad.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 246 kb/s
    Stream #7:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 39 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #7:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #8, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'gram.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 294 kb/s
    Stream #8:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 86 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #8:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #9, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'htv.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:12.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 238 kb/s
    Stream #9:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 29 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #9:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #10, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'its1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 238 kb/s
    Stream #10:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 31 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #10:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #11, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'its2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 241 kb/s
    Stream #11:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 34 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #11:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #12, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'lwt.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 239 kb/s
    Stream #12:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 30 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #12:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #13, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sou.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 247 kb/s
    Stream #13:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 39 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #13:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #14, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'stv.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 257 kb/s
    Stream #14:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 51 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #14:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #15, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'tha.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 454 kb/s
    Stream #15:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 245 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #15:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #16, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'tlc.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 275 kb/s
    Stream #16:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 67 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #16:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #17, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'tsw.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 457 kb/s
    Stream #17:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 251 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #17:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #18, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'ttt.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 258 kb/s
    Stream #18:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 51 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #18:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 193 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #19, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'tvam.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.82.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.31, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 383 kb/s
    Stream #19:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 352x288 [SAR 178:163 DAR 1958:1467], 251 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #19:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #20, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'tvs.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 252 kb/s
    Stream #20:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 44 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #20:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #21, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'tww.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 277 kb/s
    Stream #21:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 69 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #21:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #22, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'utv.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 443 kb/s
    Stream #22:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 234 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #22:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #23, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'wtv.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 431 kb/s
    Stream #23:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 224 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #23:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #24, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'ytv.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 332 kb/s
    Stream #24:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 123 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #24:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55ad3b4d4a00] No such filter: ' '
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

The `layout` code has now become extremely complex, but I've carefully followed the 4x4 example as given in the manual [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xstack) and I don't think I'm doing much wrong. Breaking down and reordering the `layout` code I used above looks like this:

```
input1(0, 0)          | input6 (w0, 0)           | input11(w0+w4, 0)          | input16(w0+w4+w8, 0)          | input21(w0+w4+w8+w12, 0)
input2(0, h0)         | input7 (w0, h0)          | input12(w0+w4, h0)         | input17(w0+w4+w8, h0)         | input22(w0+w4+w8+w12, h0)
input3(0, h0+h1)      | input8 (w0, h0+h1)       | input13(w0+w4, h0+h1)      | input18(w0+w4+w8, h0+h1)      | input23(w0+w4+w8+w12, h0+h1)
input4(0, h0+h1+h2)   | input9 (w0, h0+h1+h2)    | input14(w0+w4, h0+h1+h2)   | input19(w0+w4+w8, h0+h1+h2)   | input24(w0+w4+w8+w12, h0+h1+h2)
input5(0, h0+h1+h2+h3)| input10(w0, h0+h1+h2+h3) | input15(w0+w4, h0+h1+h2+h3)| input20(w0+w4+w8, h0+h1+h2+h3)| input25(w0+w4+w8+w12, h0+h1+h2+h3)
```

To my mind, `w12` and `h3` would logically be the next set of width and height parameters to add on in order to make the grid expansion from 4x4 to 5x5 work. Is that what's causing the code to choke? If it's not this, it's not obvious to me what it might be, as I've checked the whole code as thoroughly as possible.

Once again, I'll be very grateful for your assistance.

Thanks very much, Clive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `No such filter: ' '`

Some of your backslashes (`\`) have spaces after them. Remove the spaces:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4 -i c.mp4 -i d.mp4 -i e.mp4 -i f.mp4 -i g.mp4 -i h.mp4 -i i.mp4 -i j.mp4 -i k.mp4 -i l.mp4 -i m.mp4 -i n.mp4 -i o.mp4 -i p.mp4 -i q.mp4 -i r.mp4 -i s.mp4 -i t.mp4 -i u.mp4 -i v.mp4 -i w.mp4 -i x.mp4 -i y.mp4 \
 -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v0];[1:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v1];[2:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v2]; \
     [3:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v3];[4:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v4];[5:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v5]; \
     [6:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v6];[7:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v7];[8:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v8]; \
     [9:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v9];[10:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v10];[11:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v11]; \
     [12:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v12];[13:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v13];[14:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v14]; \
     [15:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v15];[16:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v16];[17:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v17]; \
     [18:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v18];[19:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v19];[20:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v20]; \
     [21:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v21];[22:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v22];[23:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v23]; \
     [24:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v24]; \
     [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4][v5][v6][v7][v8][v9][v10][v11][v12][v13][v14][v15][v16][v17][v18][v19][v20][v21][v22][v23][v24]xstack=inputs=25:layout=0_0|0_h0|0_h0+h1|0_h0+h1+h2|0_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0_0|w0_h0|w0_h0+h1|w0_h0+h1+h2|w0_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0+w4_0|w0+w4_h0|w0+w4_h0+h1|w0+w4_h0+h1+h2|w0+w4_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0+w4+w8_0|w0+w4+w8_h0|w0+w4+w8_h0+h1|w0+w4+w8_h0+h1+h2|w0+w4+w8_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0+w4+w8+w12_0|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0+h1|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0+h1+h2|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0+h1+h2+h3; \
     [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a][6:a][7:a][8:a][9:a][10:a][11:a][12:a][13:a][14:a][15:a][16:a][17:a][18:a][19:a][20:a][21:a][22:a][23:a][24:a]amix=inputs=25" \
output.mp4
```

Or make the command one long line:

`ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4 -i c.mp4 -i d.mp4 -i e.mp4 -i f.mp4 -i g.mp4 -i h.mp4 -i i.mp4 -i j.mp4 -i k.mp4 -i l.mp4 -i m.mp4 -i n.mp4 -i o.mp4 -i p.mp4 -i q.mp4 -i r.mp4 -i s.mp4 -i t.mp4 -i u.mp4 -i v.mp4 -i w.mp4 -i x.mp4 -i y.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v0];[1:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v1];[2:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v2];[3:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v3];[4:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v4];[5:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v5];[6:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v6];[7:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v7];[8:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v8];[9:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v9];[10:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v10];[11:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v11];[12:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v12];[13:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v13];[14:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v14];[15:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v15];[16:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v16];[17:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v17];[18:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v18];[19:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v19];[20:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v20];[21:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v21];[22:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v22];[23:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v23];[24:v]scale=iw/5:-1[v24];[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4][v5][v6][v7][v8][v9][v10][v11][v12][v13][v14][v15][v16][v17][v18][v19][v20][v21][v22][v23][v24]xstack=inputs=25:layout=0_0|0_h0|0_h0+h1|0_h0+h1+h2|0_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0_0|w0_h0|w0_h0+h1|w0_h0+h1+h2|w0_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0+w4_0|w0+w4_h0|w0+w4_h0+h1|w0+w4_h0+h1+h2|w0+w4_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0+w4+w8_0|w0+w4+w8_h0|w0+w4+w8_h0+h1|w0+w4+w8_h0+h1+h2|w0+w4+w8_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0+w4+w8+w12_0|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0+h1|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0+h1+h2|w0+w4+w8+w12_h0+h1+h2+h3;[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a][6:a][7:a][8:a][9:a][10:a][11:a][12:a][13:a][14:a][15:a][16:a][17:a][18:a][19:a][20:a][21:a][22:a][23:a][24:a]amix=inputs=25" output.mp4`